# jQuery Looping Each to Build Html List

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each

I need to parse ajax error.

Here is my code.

```
error:function(data){
        var errors = data.responseJSON;

        errorsHtml = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><ul>';
        $.each( errors, function(key, value) {
            errorsHtml += '<li>'+ errors[key] + '</li>'; //showing only the first error.
        });
        errorsHtml += '</ul></div>';
        alert(errorsHtml);
},
```

The output is

```
<div class="alert alert-danger"><ul><li>The Address Name field is required.,The Recipient field is required.,The Address field is required.</li></ul></div>
```

I couldn't do it like

```
<div class="alert alert-danger>
<ul>
    <li>The Address Name field is required.</li>
    <li>The Recipient field is required.</li>
    <li>The Address field is required.</li>
</ul>
```

Where am I making mistake ?

Comment: what is the value of `data.responseJSON`, looks like it is an array with `,` separated string value

Comment: {"errors":["The Address Name field is required.","The Recipient field is required.","The Address field is required."]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your content, the `errors` is an object which has a key called `errors` which is having an array of error messages.

So what you need is to iterate over the `errors` array so

```
var errors = data.responseJSON;

errorsHtml = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><ul>';
$.each(errors.errors, function (key, value) {
    errorsHtml += '<li>' + value + '</li>'; //showing only the first error.
});
errorsHtml += '</ul></div>';
alert(errorsHtml);
```

---

Another simple way is

```
var errorsHtml = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><ul>';
errorsHtml += '<li>' + errors.errors.join('</li><li>') + '</li>';
errorsHtml += '</ul></div>';
```